# How to set keys for HOC components?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, high-order-component

```js
class Demo extends Component {
  render() {
    const { list } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        {list.map(this._renderItem)}
      </div>
    )
  }
  _renderItem = item => {
    const Item = withSwipeDelete(
      <div>{item.id}</div>,
      () => console.log('callback')
    )
    return <Item />
  }
}
```

It's an example for my code, which warning: **Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop**.

So I tried:

```js
  _renderItem = item => {
    const Item = withSwipeDelete(
      <div key={item.id}>{item.id}</div>, // add key here
      () => console.log('callback')
    )
    return <Item />
  }
```

And this:

```js
  _renderItem = item => {
    const Item = withSwipeDelete(
      <div>{item.id}</div>,
      () => console.log('callback')
    )
    return <Item key={item.id} /> // add key here
  }
```

Both not work.

`withSwipeDelete` is a *higher-order-components*:

```js
export default function withSwipeDelete(Cell, onDelete) {
  return class extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          {Cell}
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second solution that you have posted should be working:

```
_renderItem = item => {
    const Item = withSwipeDelete(
      <div>{item.id}</div>,
      () => console.log('callback')
    )
    return <Item key={item.id} /> // add key here
}
```

I have tried it here https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-http-3w3ki

As long as the id is unique, no error is present in the console.

Explanation: React would require you to put a key in places, where you are trying too render an array of items. If we simplify your code (regardless of the HOC), you are actually rendering an array inside the `<div>` in the main render. That translated means that you have an array of `<Item />` components (since this is what `_renderItem` would return), thus, you need a key for each of those `<Item />`.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that's right. I miss a key for another map.